# what are all the differences between running python code in apache2+uwsgi vs. command line?

Tags: python, apache2, execution, uwsgi

consider the following python code (running as apache server's user in all cases):

```
import subprocess as sp
_fname_in ='/path/to/existing/dir/file_in.pdf'
_fname_out='/path/to/existing/dir/file_out.pdf'
_from_page=1
_to_page=4
cmd = [
    '/usr/bin/pdftk',
    'A=%(_fname_in)s'%locals(),
    'cat',
    '%(_from_page)s-%(_to_page)s'%locals(),
    'output',
    '%(_fname_out)s'%locals(),
]
p = sp.Popen(cmd,stdout=sp.PIPE,stderr=sp.PIPE)
output, errors = p.communicate()
```

The code above behaves differently when running in uwsgi, vs. ipython:

- ipython - simply works.
- when accessed via apache + uwsgi, the code simply gets stuck on the last line.

When THAT happens, ps output shows 2 processes related to that command:

1. shell invocation with PPID of the uwsgi python's PID, with cmd line as follows:

   sh -c /usr/bin/pdftk A /path/to/existing/dir/file_in.pdf
2. the pdftk process itself, with this "A <>" something.

Note something replaced `'='` with `' '`
Now, if I am running that very command from ipython, I am getting 3rd behaviour: a syntax error from pdftk.
What confuses me is the fact the same command, under the SAME SHELL renders different results.

Please explain why this may happen....

Comment: Are you sure the argument list is actually truncated (everything from "cat" onwards is missing) when launched from uwsgi? Does `ps wwaux` not show more? What does 'with this "A <>" something' mean? What's the exact error message pdftk returns when you run the mangled command? Can you try running uwsgi with the `--close-on-exec`option (see http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/wiki/ThingsToKnow)?

Comment: Thanks for the attempt, yes, I'm sure the argument list is truncated "properly" (that is `ps wwaux` shows it)
The A <> means that in stead of e.g.: `pdftk A=/path/to/existing/dir/file_in.pdf`
I am getting: `pdftk A /path/to/existing/dir/file_in.pdf` in `ps wwaux` output. that is `=` is replaced by `\ ` (space).
I shall look into `--close-on-exec` option, thanks for the hint!